# How does custom HTML code work in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Pretty new here, so sorry if the post isn't clear at first!

I'm trying to get a Custom HTML Tag to work from Google Tag Manager. The tag fires just fine, but the JS code inside the tag doesn't seem to do anything. It's supposed to update an Adroll conversion, but nothing happens.

I'm more wondering if this type of JS would even work in GTM? Like the fact that it uses a specific adroll function, how would that even work without access to a larger library?

```
<script> try{__adroll.track("pageView", {"segment_name":"eea7cf78"}) 
} catch(err) {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how would that even work without access to a larger library?

It would not. If you have not loaded a library that defines an `_adroll` object with at least a `track` method, then this will give an error.

You probably cannot see this error because of the try/catch block. The idea behind try/catch is that you can prevent a script from going into an undefined state bey handling errors in the `catch` branch in a controlled manner.

In this case however, it is used merely to hide an error. The problem with that is that now you do not know what is wrong :-). Error messages are useful, and suppressing them is not.

There should be an accompanying tracking library, that you can either load via a script tag in the same custom tag, in another custom tag that fires before your tracking tag (best done via [tag sequencing](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6238868?hl=en)), or ideally Adroll would provide a custom GTM template for their tag. At least their support should provide instructions where to get their tracking library.

Also remove the try/catch, since it does nothing but to obscure a problem that should be fixed (and also creates a performance hit in the process).